# Vue Js Applications throws Js Expected Errors

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, vue.js

I am learning `Vue js` with `Visual Studio 2017` . I am trying to build up applications with several buttons . I want to display the message when the specific buttons it clicked . but when i complied this code ,I am getting following error.

> **Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning TS1005  (JS) ':' expected.  VuejsApp JavaScript Content Files   C:\Users\Khundokar Nirjor\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\VuejsApp\VuejsApp\src\App.vue   21  Active**

Here is my `App.vue` code:

```
<template>
    <div id="databinding">
        <div id="counter-event-example">
            <p style="font-size:25px;">Language displayed : <b>{{ languageclicked }}</b></p>
            <button-counter v-for="(item, index) in languages"
                            v-bind:item="item"
                            v-bind:index="index"
                            v-on:showlanguage="languagedisp"></button-counter>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    import Vue from 'vue';
    export default {
        name: 'app',
        components: {

        },
        Vue.component('button-counter', {// error on this line

            template: '<button v-on:click = "displayLanguage(item)"><span style = "font-size:25px;">{{ item }}</span></button>',
            data: function () {
                return {
                    counter: 0
                }
            },
            props: ['item'],
            methods: {
                displayLanguage: function (lng) {
                    console.log(lng);
                    this.$emit('showlanguage', lng);
                }
            },
        })


      var vm= new Vue({// error on this line
            el: '#databinding',
            data: {
                languageclicked: "",
                languages: ["Java", "PHP", "C++", "C", "Javascript", "C#", "Python", "HTML"]
            },
            methods: {
                languagedisp: function (a) {
                    this.languageclicked = a;
                }
            }
        })



    }

</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Comment: it looks like your code is inside an object

Comment: Can you please explain your opinion??

Comment: it's like: 
`{
  var a = 1
}`
it's a statement inside an object.
object should be `{ key: value }`

Comment: the `button-counter` component should be inside the `components: {

        },` right above it

Comment: the vm part should be outside the object

Comment: Please post your answer

Answer (score 0):

the problem here is because the code is inside an object.
if you move the `button-counter` component inside `components: { }` right above it,
and the vm part outside the object, that should solve this problem.